# Calculated Column Not Displaying Anything

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time

I have this really odd issue that works in 1 document library (first image) and doesn't for another (second image).

I have 2 columns, column 1 called `Published Date (Flow)` that is of type string (single line of text) and column 2 called `Valid Till` that is of type calculated (date).

Based on the `Review Period (Months)` column (type number), I am supposed to calculate the valid till date from the published date.

[image]

[image]

The formula I am using for the calculated column is:

```
= [Published Date (Flow)] + ([Review Period (Months)]*30)
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better not to use a single line of text column to fill in `Published Date (Flow)`.

The workaround I can think of is to use a date column named `Published Date (Flow)`. Then add a calculated column with another name.

Set the formula as:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Published Date (Flow)]),"NA",[Published Date (Flow)])
```

Then edit the view to show the calculated column instead of the original date column.

Then you can display NA and the formula you are using will work.